# How to add breadcrumbs for view page?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have added content type breadcrumbs, but I don't know how to add view's breadcrumbs
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your requirement by installing any of the below modules:

1. [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)

> Many new features have been added including support for Views, Panels,
>   Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows
>   contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for module pages and
>   theme templates. These are implemented using optional, independent
>   submodules that depend on the main Custom Breadcrumbs module.

2. [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site! Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for
>   any page with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!

You can also follow this [link](http://www.leccionespracticas.com/informatica-web/drupal-informatica-web/drupal-7-path-breadcrumbs-in-views-page-solved).

Comment: Can you give me a detailed step?I installed Path Breadcrumbs

Comment: Please follow the last link mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Can you give me Custom Breadcrumbs picturetutorial? picture

Comment: Can you give me custom Breadcrumbs picture or video tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your custom breadcrumbs in  `template.php` file as your requirement.